# AngularJS initialize controller variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using an initialization function init() within most of my controllers to setup controller specific variables. I'm finding I'm doing it in most controllers so I assuming this is common but I cannot find any documentation. As I see the options are as follows:

1. leave as is
2. use run or provider service

   ```
   (function () {

   'use strict';

   CompanyController.$inject = ['CompanyFactory','LocationService'];
   function CompanyController(CompanyFactory,LocationService) {

       let vm = this;

         // Initialize function  
       function init() {
           vm.company = {
               solutions: CompanyFactory.getSolutions(),
           };
           // set $location 
           LocationService.setLocation('company-page');
       }

       init();

   }

   angular.module('app.company', [])
       .controller('CompanyController', CompanyController)


   })();
   ```

Comment: What do you want?please explain more

Comment: There is no options. I believe.You have to make init() calls in each controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller [lifecycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) were introduced in AngularJS 1.5. `$onInit` hook is supposed to play exactly this role:

```
this.$onInit = function () { ... }
```

`$onInit` hook is a replacement for pre-link function. It is executed by the compiler.
It may not be executed if a controller doesn't belong to a directive (`ng-controller` is a directive, too) but is instantiated directly with `$controller`, like route controller. In this case `this.$onInit()` should be called explicitly in constructor.

It should be noticed that in original snippet `function init() {...}` doesn't play significant role. It isn't exposed as a method, so it cannot help a controller to be more testable or extensible.

Comment: It is related to components not to controllers.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Lifecycle hooks were introduced as a step towards A2. It is specific to *compiler*, not components. Lifecycle hooks are documented in components section because components benefited most from them.

Comment: @estus thank you! btw, I only placed the function it in the controller for brevity sake